# Rascal AST visit access annotation

Tags: rascal

Ok, so I would like to access a node's annotations when I visit it. To give an example:

```
visit (myAST) {
  case someNode(str name): {
    // How do I now access the @src annotation of someNode here?
  }
};
```

I have already tried the following but this does not work:

```
visit (myAST) {
  case someNode(str name): {
    parents = getTraversalContext();

    iprintln(parents[0]); // This print shows someNode with the @src annotation.
    iprintln(parents[0]@src); // This gives the error: get-annotation not supported on value at...
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is my approach wrong?

Comment: The second solution would work if you match `parents[0]` against the type for which the annotation is declared or against `node`. This is because the `getAnnotation` function is only defined for `node` and not for `value`. However, the solution Paul has is to be preferred over using `getTraversalContext`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question, the best way to do this is to introduce a variable, say `sn` in the pattern and to use that to fetch the annotation

```
visit (myAST) {
   case sn:someNode(str name): {
     // Access the @src annotation of someNode here by sn@src
   }
 };
```

As a side note: you use the function `getTraversalContext` but I strongly advice you to avoid it since it is experimental and will very likely change in the future. Admitted: we should have marked it as such.